# Recent Install, Failed to initialize the Nvidia GPU

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, xorg

I've had a problem ever since installing Ubuntu three days ago. running startx shows an error in /var/log/Xorg.0.log

````
(EE) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:43:0:0.```

(EE) no screens found (EE)
````

He Nvidia GPU is at least detected

lspci | grep VGA

```
2b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 [GeForce GTX 760] (rev A1)
```

I'm not sure what the solution is, I've tried deleting xorg.conf, and reinstalling xorg and my Nvidia drivers, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Which Nvidia driver are you using, and how are you installing it? Your 760 may be limited to a 390 or 470 driver.

Comment: I'm using the 470 driver, yeah. I'm installing in the exact way the Ubuntu docs say to.

Comment: Selecting Ubuntu (safe graphics) when my boot stick is in works, but all that does is go to the install screen

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you trying to install? Which kernel is it using?  Did you turn off secure boot (in UEFI settings/aka BIOS)?

Comment: I found out what's causing the issue. Running Ubuntu as a fresh install with "nomodeset" works, but updating the drivers to allow multiple monitors breaks it

Comment: I am using the most recent LTS of Ubuntu, and I have no idea what kernel. I didn't change any UEFI settings.

Comment: Secure Boot was already disabled

Comment: Probably a 5.15 kernel (uname -a to show this). An hwe package would give the 6.2 kernels, but with old hardware, either should work. Last time I ran a GT640, it was with the 345 driver, don't have that setup anymore.  looks like the nouveau driver works, maybe the cleanup of old Nvidia drivers was not through enough.  dpkg -l |grep -i nvidia and sudo apt purge every packge with nvidia in name. then try the ubuntu-drivers autoinstall.

Comment: I was using the 6.2 kernel and the drivers weren't purged first before updating. however, fixing that didn't help, so I'm running low on ideas. Maybe getting rid of the proprietary drivers altogether would help?

Comment: Removing the Nvidia drivers is a temporary solution, I'll just have to do without the multiple monitors

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I have found is to remove all of the Nvidia drivers and modules altogether with

```
sudo apt purge nvidia.*
reboot
```

Comment: I have 33 packages related to nvidia, only 10 of which start with nvidia, none of which match "nvidia.*". Start with nvidia* (no dot), then look at the rest with dpkg -l |grep nvidia  Probably all should be purged for a clean start with a new nvidia driver.

Comment: installing nvidia drivers at all is what causes the issue, though

Comment: more specifically the module itself